# Mac terminal settings

Tags: mac, terminal

I'm on a mac and I use terminal (Amazing)

I was wondering if anyone knows how I can change the default setting of a new terminal to remain the same for all subsequent terminals?

For example - I have pro as my default settings. If I hit ctrl and n it opens a white terminal instead of a pro. I'd like to make it so either a different colour terminal always opens up or it at least sticks to pro.

Answer (score 4):

Note that in the preferences under "Startup" you control what the first window will look like, but under "Settings" you control what a new window will look like. Also, you can't just highlight a setting to make it the default, you have to select the setting and then press the "Default" button.

Does any of that help or make sense?

Comment: Ah thanks I never noticed that before!!! Any idea how to get it so a different colour screen pops up all the time?

Comment: It turns out that Terminal is scriptable. Daniel Jalkut has developed a "Random Color Terminal" script -- http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/220/random-color-terminal

Answer (score 2):

The default setting **remains** the same for all subsequent terminals.

Try quitting and restarting Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

See if this may be of some use: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070604100629346

Comment: He doesn't want all windows to look different, but to look the same. Just not the default style.